# Bounds for singular values of block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds, singular-values

Let
\begin{align}
M = \begin{pmatrix} A \\ v^T \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
with $A \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n \times k}$, $n\geq k$, $\text{rank}(A) = k$, and $v^T \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{1 \times k}$.
Moreover, I know bounds for the sum of every row $A_i$ of $A$ and for $v^T$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
 \varepsilon &\leq \sum_j A_{i,j} \leq \sqrt{2} \quad \forall i=1,...,n \\
 \varepsilon &\leq \sum_jv^T_j \leq \sqrt{2}
\end{align}

I'm interested in the condition number of $M$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\text{cond}(M) := \frac{\sigma_{max}(M)}{\sigma_{min}(M)},
\end{align}
where $\sigma_{max}(M)$ and $\sigma_{min}(M)$ represent the largest and smallest non-zero singular value of $M$, respectively.

**Question**

Is it possible to bound $\text{cond}(M)$ by information that I have regarding $A$ and $v^T$? It seems (numerical experiment) that
\begin{align}
\text{cond}(A) \not \leq \text{cond}{M},
\end{align}
which I hoped for at first. I guess it makes sense that this does not hold true; I'd have to include information regarding $v^T$.
The relation $\sigma_k(M) = \sqrt{\lambda_k(M^T M )} =  \sqrt{\lambda_k(A^T A + vv^T )} $ seems useful but didn't help me. Even with (I hope this is correct)
\begin{align}
 \sigma_{max}(M) \leq \sigma_{max}(A) + \sigma_{max}(v^T) = \sigma_{max}(A) + ||v^T||_2
\end{align}
I only have an upper bound for the enumerator, but no lower bound for the denominator (of the expression for the condition number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your upper bound is correct, but we can do better. In particular, for any $x \in \Bbb R^k$, we have
$$
\|Mx\|_2^2 = \left\|\pmatrix{A \\ v^T} x \right\|_2^2 = \left\|\pmatrix{Ax \\ v^Tx} \right\|_2^2 = \|Ax\|_2^2 + \|v^Tx\|_2^2 \leq [\sigma_\max(A)^2 + \|v\|_2^2] \cdot \|x\|_2^2.
$$
With that, we can conclude that
$$
\sigma_\max(M) = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Mx\|_2}{\|x\|_2} \leq \sqrt{\sigma_\max(A)^2 + \|v\|_2^2}. 
$$
We can apply a to get the lower bound $\sigma_\max(M) \geq \max\{\|v\|_2, \sigma_\max(A)\}$.

For lower bounds, we can apply similar ideas. Note that $\sigma_\min(M) = \min_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Mx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$. Using the ideas above, we can reach the conclusion that
$$
\sigma_\min(A) \leq \sigma_\min(M) \leq \sqrt{\sigma_\min(A)^2 + \|v\|_2^2}.
$$
Putting everything together, we can conclude that
$$
\frac{\sigma_\max(A)}{\sqrt{\sigma_\min(A)^2 + \|v\|_2^2}}\leq
\operatorname{cond}(M) \leq \frac{\sqrt{\sigma_\max(A)^2 + \|v\|_2^2}}{\sigma_\min(A)}.
$$